# does cmake take the place of configure?

Tags: cmake

all of a sudden I have started seeing this cmake doohickey. Great, one more thing to learn now that I'm used to configure/ make / make install

how does it work and what is the equivalent of configure --help with cmake, to show the build options of a particular source code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [run CMake in interactive mode](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt%3a-i) to get useful information about (and the ability to set) each cache variable in the current CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake -i <path-to-source>
```

If you just want to [list all the non-advanced cached variables](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt%3a-LAH), run:

```
cmake -L <path-to-source>
```

For any of these which are documented CMake variables (e.g. CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX), you can get further info by running:

```
cmake --help-variable CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/autotools-to-cmake.html